# How to Install SSL on aws Lightsail windows server for .net application

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have my domain name in godaddy and deployed the application on AWS lightsail windows VM, I need to enable https for my website. Can anyone guide me how to enable ssl.

Thanks,
Ramkumar K

Comment: Please check the [lightsail ssl guide](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-tls-ssl-certificates-in-lightsail-https). Basically it doesn't matter if the service is implemented as php or .net, it's the same. You will have to assign a certificate to the load balancer or the cloudfront distribution (cdn).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use CloudFront distribution in front of your LightSail instance

I found this article blog with very detailed instructions on how to set it up:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Any reference for .net web application?

Comment: SSL installation is not related to what web application installed, and CloudFront ofload SSL connection, so it's like intermediate lier